# My issue about Android Studio 3.3.2 Library Revisions 28.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: have you update your `gradle-wrapper.properties` ?

Comment: make sure u change gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties file like this
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

Comment: I changed it but still not work

Comment: When providing text-based information, please do not supply it as screenshots - would you edit this question to supply that config file as text? The question is off-topic as it stands. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `gradle offline work` from `android studio` Settings

In windows :

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck
>   Offline Work

In Mac :

> Android Studio > Prefrences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck
>   Offline Work